# Column values to matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the values of column A are labels. I select this column A and project its values as a matrix. The following is my code.

```
data = pd.read_csv(fn, encoding="utf-8", delimiter="\t")
cat_cols = pd.get_dummies(data['A'])
cats1 = cat_cols.columns.values
y = cat_cols.as_matrix()
```

If the number of different labels in A is 177 and the number of rows in data is 10, then to my understanding the dimension of y would be 10 * 177.

Now I read another dataframe where the values of the column B is a subset of A. How can I project column B with refers to matrix A so I can have the same dimension (177)?